# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/election/1) on Islam has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Medi1Saif]

[image: Farhan]

[image: goldPseudo]

Since this was your "graduation" election, these are now your inaugural "full" moderators — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes! And let's also thank the pro-tem mods who helped this site go through it's Beta phase!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/election/1) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5677149970235392).

Comment: This was a very close one. Maybe one of the closest elections in which 4 candidates were in such a close race for only 3 positions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367434/391772

Comment: Congratulations

Answer (score 6):

I want to thank the community for voting in this election. I will try my best to fulfill the duties of moderator, InShaAllah.

I always try to be transparent. My belief is that discussion can resolve conflicts, and I am happy to do it here.

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations to the new moderators!

Definitely, those who became full moderators (@goldPseudo & @Medi1Saif) from pro-tem moderators have already given inexpressible effort to the community. Now, they can serve the community with more courage.

The fresh moderator (@Farhan) will get the opportunity to serve the community and to learn new things by doing.

I will help them and give them full support if they need any from me.

My special thanks go to the 57 voters (including me!) in the election who voted for the candidates. Without them, the election was not possible.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Congratulation for the community to finally have voted moderators based on their choice,

Congratulation to anybody who particpated, either by nominating, voting and asking questions since the beginning of the election announcement.

I'm very happy that we had an election and at least 2 fresh particpants/candidates.

Congratulation to Farhan for the new diamond sign and the corresponding tasks and responsabilties.

Congratulation and better luck in a next election for Enamul Hassan I'm glad that you have partcipated.

Goldpseudo I hope you'll stay as you are, I think IslamSE as it is now, is to a fair portion a merit of your efforts and work to keep the site clean and welcoming!

I hope this election would wake up a few people who could be more active.

I'm however a bit sad that shi'a are not represented in the actual moderator team and hope this will not have any impact on their particpation on the site. We are a pluralistic site and we don't want to change that.

Another thing that I hope will increase in future elections is the particpation and voting culture! 158 votes or 57 ballots doesn't sound like much to me...